# How to resize base64 image in nativescript-vue by height and width?

Tags: javascript, nativescript

After selecting an image from image-picker, I want to resize that image in native-script vue.
Please help me.

I used resize-base64 plugin but its not working :

```
var resizebase64 = require('resize-base64');  

var img = resizebase64(base64, maxWidth, maxHeight);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong that JS plugin is for browser, uses Canvas which won't be available in {N} environment. You might to convert it to a actual image and use [nativescript-bitmap-factory](https://github.com/mkloubert/nativescript-bitmap-factory) to resize it.